# Is it possible to use tracker servers to set up my own peer-to-peer network?

Tags: c, networking, p2p, bittorrent

If I want to develop a C application to share files over a p2p network similar to how Bittorrent allows you to share files over a p2p connection by finding peers with Tracker servers, is this possible? Could I use tracker servers that already exist Or are tracker servers owned by someone who also owns rights to the client software used to connect to the tracker servers.

Comment: I think tracker server only track the metadata of a torrent. the client tells the server what all metadata/torrents it has and server logs/keeps clients info for other client which are trying to download the same file/torrent data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trackers `servers` are part of the `BitTorrent` protocol. The way it works is you need to have a `BitTorrent` `client` running at both the `server` and the `client`, and they only understand the `.torrent` file. You can make things working but at the "other" end, you need to have an instance of your application running, which is I think what you don't want.